# Unable to create database connection with multiple dataSources

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I am getting the following error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field dataSource in com.domain.ws.actuator.RandomActuator required a bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' that could not be found.
    - Bean method 'dataSource' not loaded because @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.datasource.type) did not find property 'spring.datasource.type'
    - Bean method 'dataSource' not loaded because @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.datasource.jndi-name) did not find property 'jndi-name'
    - Bean method 'dataSource' not loaded because @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.boot.jta.XADataSourceWrapper; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans

Action:

Consider revisiting the conditions above or defining a bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' in your configuration.
```

I uniquely identified the dataSources names with `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.fooDataSource")` then put `spring.fooDataSource.url: ${dbURI}` in the `yml` file. Example:

Config class

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource({"classpath:application.yml"})
public class RequestDataSource {

    /*******************************
     *      foo Datasource     *
     * *****************************/
    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.fooDataSource")
    public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    /*******************************
     * foo Transaction manager *
     * *****************************/
    @Bean(name="tm1")
    @Primary
    @Autowired
    DataSourceTransactionManager tm1(@Qualifier("primaryDataSource") DataSource datasource) {
        DataSourceTransactionManager txm  = new DataSourceTransactionManager(datasource);
        return txm;
    }

}
```

second dataSource class

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource({"classpath:application.yml"})
public class KeyviewDataSource {

    /*******************************
     *     Second Datasource      *
     * *****************************/
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.secondDataSource")
    public DataSource secondaryDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    /*******************************
     * Second Transaction manager *
     * *****************************/
    @Bean(name="tm2")
    @Autowired
    DataSourceTransactionManager tm2(@Qualifier("secondaryDataSource") DataSource datasource) {
        DataSourceTransactionManager txm  = new DataSourceTransactionManager(datasource);
        return txm;
    }

}
```

Application.yml

```
spring:

  fooDataSource.url: ${dbURI}
  fooDataSource.username: ${dbUsername}
  fooDataSource.password: ${dbPassword}
  fooDataSource.driverClassName: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

  secondDataSource.url: ${dbURIkeyview}
  secondDataSource.username: ${dbUSERNAMEkeyview}
  secondDataSource.password: ${dbPasswordKeyview}
  secondDataSource.driverClassName: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

I am using gradle and in this module I did add the dependency it needs:

```
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa', version: springBootVersion
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-java8
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-java8', version: '5.0.0.CR1'
```

----------------------------------Update 1----------------------------------

## Note

In my applications.yml file Intellij is highlighting my dataSources in yellow and when hover over them it reads `"Cannot resolve configuration property"`

-------------------------Update 2------------------------------

Due to so many changes I created a new question that is related to this one[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40746554/could-not-find-version-optional-for-arguments)

-------------------------------Update 3------------------------------

I got rid of the issue with update one by creating a `spring-configuration-metadata.json` file
 and doing the following:

```
{
    "properties": [
        {
            "name": "spring.fooDataSource.username",
            "type": "java.lang.String",
            "description": "Description for spring.requestDataSource.username."
        },
        {
            "name": "spring.fooDataSource.url",
            "type": "java.lang.String",
            "description": "Description for spring.requestDataSource.url."
        },
        {
            "name": "spring.fooDataSource.driverClassName",
            "type": "java.lang.String",
            "description": "Description for spring.requestDataSource.driverClassName."
        },
```

and placing it in the resources folder.

Comment: is it okay if you try it with one database ?

Comment: @NikolayRusev when I was using `spring.database.uri:` type convention yes it worked just fine for one dataSource. But I need to two dataSources and now I am having this issue.

Comment: @NikolayRusev please see update one

Comment: @NikolayRusev please see update 2

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your `yml` file. You can easily setup two databases in spring boot. Simply change your file `Application.yml` to:

```
spring:
  fooDataSource.url: ${dbURI}
  fooDataSource.username: ${dbUsername}
  fooDataSource.password: ${dbPassword}
  fooDataSource.driverClassName: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

second:
  secondDataSource.url: ${dbURIkeyview}
  secondDataSource.username: ${dbUSERNAMEkeyview}
  secondDataSource.password: ${dbPasswordKeyview}
  secondDataSource.driverClassName: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

and then your config class:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource({"classpath:application.yml"})
public class RequestDataSource {

    /*******************************
     *      foo Datasource     *
     * *****************************/
    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.fooDataSource")
    public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    /*******************************
    *     Second Datasource      *
   * *****************************/
   @Bean
   @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="second.secondDataSource")
   public DataSource secondaryDataSource() {
      return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
   }

}
```

because two databases I think cannot be prefixed with same prefix.

Comment: I still got the same error with your solution. However I think you might be right but it didn't solve it. Thank you for your efforts.

Comment: I think intellij tells you that cannot resolve properties with dollar sign .. ${dbURI} , ${dbUsername}. Try to hardcode them for testing purposes.

Comment: No I have tried that too. Thank you. I think it has to do with creating my own meta data when using `@ConfigurationProperties` I am investigating now.